Flutter RadioListTile not changing state
In my Flutter app, I have a bool class so that when a button is pressed, the bool class changes state to true.
So in another widget, I state that if bool is true, then a RadioListTile is shown. The RadiolistTile shows right, but unfortunately, it doesn't change when I press one of the buttons.
I tried to initialize it with an initializer but I get this error after the bool state is changed to true.
dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<MediaQuery>() or dependOnInheritedElement() was called before _GenAdFormState.initState() completed.

as in the code
List<Widget>? carsToUse;
Widget? currentOption;

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    carsToUse = [ primaryCar(), ////this is a method I built. 
                  secondaryCar(),
                  ];
          }

So I call the List<Widget>? carsToUse; in the build method.
bool hasUploaded = false;

in the build method:
...after some widgets:

checkIfHasUploaded(),
...other widgets


checkIfHasUploaded(){
if(hasUploaded){
return StatefulBuilder(
   builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState){
        List<Widget>? carsToUse;
        Widget? currentOption;
        carsToUse = [
                     primaryCar(), //This method is created returning a widget
                     secondaryCar(),
                  ];
        return Column(
          children: [
              RadioListTile(
                  activeColor: activeColor,
                  title: primaryCar(),
                  value: carsToUse[0],
                  groupValue: currentOption,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                  if (value != null) {
                     setState(() {
                         currentOption = value;
                     });
                   }
                 },
             ),
           RadioListTile(
                activeColor: activeColor,
                title: secondaryCar(),
                value: carsToUse[1],
                groupValue: currentOption,
                onChanged: (value) {
                    if (value != null) {
                       setState(() {
                           currentOption = value;
                         });
                       }
                     },
                 )
           ]
        );
       }
    );
   }
else {
return some widgets
 }
}

With this, I can see everything works well, but I can't make a selection.

Possible issues can be

Initialization in StatefulBuilder: Declaring List? carsToUse; and Widget? currentOption; inside the StatefulBuilder causes reinitialization every time the widget rebuilds. This prevents the RadioListTile from maintaining its state.

State Handling: The StatefulBuilder only allows state updates locally within its scope. This might not propagate changes effectively.


Corrected Code
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  bool hasUploaded = false;
  List<Widget> carsToUse = [];
  Widget? currentOption;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    carsToUse = [
      primaryCar(),
      secondaryCar(),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              hasUploaded = true;
            });
          },
          child: Text("Toggle State"),
        ),
        if (hasUploaded)
          Column(
            children: carsToUse.map((car) {
              return RadioListTile<Widget>(
                title: car,
                value: car,
                groupValue: currentOption,
                onChanged: (Widget? value) {
                  setState(() {
                    currentOption = value;
                  });
                },
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget primaryCar() {
    return Text("Primary Car");
  }

  Widget secondaryCar() {
    return Text("Secondary Car");
  }
}


Thank you, but the problem is I'm still getting the error dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<MediaQuery>() or dependOnInheritedElement() was called before _GenAdFormState.initState() completed. when I edited my code

@VictorWoode try initializing carsToUse inside didChangeDependencies() if that make sense for your workflow and requirement
